# Did Sāyaṇa commentate on Śukla Yajurveda?

Tags: yajur-veda, shukla-yajurveda, krishna-yajurveda, sayanacharya

Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sayana) Sāyaṇa belonged to the Taittirīya Śākhā of Kṛṣṇa Yajurveda. So was his commentary on Yajurveda limited to Kṛṣṇa Yajurveda or did he commentate on Śukla Yajurveda too?

> Sāyaṇa was born to Māyaṇa and Shrimati in a Brahmin family that lived in Hampi. He had an elder brother named Madhava (sometimes identified as Vidyaranya) and a younger brother named Bhoganatha (or Somanatha). The family belonged to Bharadvaja gotra, and followed the Taittiriya Shakha (school) of the **Krishna Yajurveda**.

Comment: Why two tags for the same person?

Comment: So they can be merged eventually @Rickross

Comment: You created the tags so that they can be merged? Sorry did not understand a thing. Creating just one would have been enough. I added Sayanacharya to one of my earlier questions.

Comment: BTW Sayana has a commentary on Rig Veda but he wasn't a Rigvedi Brahmin.

Comment: Yes, instead of accidentally creating dup. tags and merging later, we can guess the possible tag synonyms and introduce all versions ourselves! After a few days merge them ourselves. Then we don't have to worry about merging at a later point :P @Rickross

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, he did.

Among the [Madhyadina and Kanva Vajasaneyi Shakhas of Shukla Yajurveda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yajurveda), Sayanacharya has a commentary on the Kanva Samhita.

A book comprised of that commentary can be purchased from [here](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/kanva-samhita-with-commentaries-of-sayana-and-anandabodha-set-of-5-volumes-old-book-NZC293/). From [the foreword/preface to Volume 1](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/kanva-samhita-with-commentaries-of-sayana-and-anandabodha-set-of-5-volumes-old-book-NZC293/#mCSB_3_container):

> We have contemplated to bring out the edition of Kanva Samhita, with Padapatha and three commentaries in four volumes. Fifth volume will consist of various indices. **The commentaries of Sayanacarya and Anandabodha have been available on the first twenty chapters**, while chapters 21-40 have been commented upon, by Anandabodha and Anantacarya.
>
> ...
>
> The edition of the Kanva Samhita has been prepared, as planned by, me earlier with Padapatha and all the three available commentaries. Of these three commentaries, Anandabodha's Bhasyasangraha alone covers all the four Dasakas - **Sayana's Vedarthaprakasa is available only on the first two Dasakas** and the remaining latter two Dasakas are commented on by Anantacarya, I could not, however much I liked to, include the Orissan commentary on the Uttarurdha attributed to Sayana in my edition, for reason I have mentioned in the Introduction. However, I must mention here, this is the first critical edition of the entire Kanva Samhita with Padapatha with accent and all the three commentaries, of which, as far as I know, Anandabodha's has been printed only in part before; and Anantacarya's was never.

Comment: I'm surprised he wrote a commentary on a Veda followed by a rival school.